# AWS Amplify Datastore - How to Create Account > Users Authorization Rules in Schema?

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

Let say I have the following schema.graphql:

```
type Account @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  users: [User] @connection(name: "AccountUsers")
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  account: Account @connection(name: "AccountUsers")
}
```

The goal is to allow each User from the Account to have access to this Account entity and to the other users from that Account using **Amazon Cognito User Pools**.

For example, I have a Settings screen where I'd like to show the account title and the list of users from your account.

Pretty common case, I assume, but didn't find much information... Thanks in advance for any help!